# How to properly export a javascript file containing text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am tried to localize my react-native app. I used this code which is working fine

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization'

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
 "en-US":{
   how:"How do you want your egg today?",
   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
   softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
   choice:"How to choose the egg"
 },
 en:{
   how:"How do you want your egg today?",
   boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
   softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
   choice:"How to choose the egg"
 },
 fr: {
   how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
   boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
   softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
   choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
 }
});

export default strings
```

I tried to use a file for each language. I changed it to this one

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization'
import en from './langs/en'
import fr from './langs/fr'

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en,
  fr,
});

export default strings
```

and `en.js` contain this code

```
export default {
    en: {
       welcome: 'Willkommen zu Reactn Native Lokalisierung Demo!',
       change: 'Sprache ändern durch Auswahl der Option unten',
       changeLanguage: 'Sprache ändern',
       english: 'Englisch',
       deutsch: 'Deutsch'
    }
}
```

Accessing the text with the following code is not working anymore:

```
<Text style={styles.welcome}>
{strings.english}
</Text>
```

Edit: I used JSON files instead and it worked fine

```
{
  "hello": "salut"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to separate your files this way, your en.js file should look like :

```
export default
{
   welcome: 'Willkommen zu Reactn Native Lokalisierung Demo!',
   change: 'Sprache ändern durch Auswahl der Option unten',
   changeLanguage: 'Sprache ändern',
   english: 'Englisch',
   deutsch: 'Deutsch'
}
```

Then it can be imported as `en`, and used as :

```
let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en,
  fr,
});
```

Otherwise you can use the spread operator with your current `en.js` file :

```
let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  ...en,
  ...fr,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's essential to note that:

```
let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en,
  fr,
});
```

is equal to:

```
let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en: en,
  fr: fr,
});
```

Which mean you'd probably have to write such a code for your template:

```
<Text style={styles.welcome}>
  {strings[this.props.currentLang].english}
</Text>
```

Note: `this.props.currentLang` in my example is a shared property from container OR parent-component.